# How worked with large shapefile using SharpMap?

Tags: shapefile, performance, sharpmap

I use SharpMap for working with shapefile. Now shapefile is big and SharpMap take a long time to loading layers. Please tell me how I can speed up working with shapefile.

Comment: You really need to show us what you are doing. For example, how are you _using_ the shapefile. Obviously there are some inherent limits (like reading from disk), but smarter use of the shapefile (like not loading areas you don't use) will help. Also, saying how big and how long it takes will help us understand if your expectations are reasonable. A small, self-contained, compileable example and a link to the data will probably help to get your question answered. Without more info, there isn't anything we can really say to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was that you were hitting a drawback of the shapefile format rather than SharpMap but [Easy GIS .NET](http://www.easygisdotnet.com/About.aspx) claims to be able to do better than SharpMap with the same format:

> The library has been designed to handle very large shapefiles, without
>   compromising performance or memory usage. For example the library is
>   capable of opening shapefiles larger than 1GB and will not crash with
>   OutOfMemoryExceptions like some other libraries. Easy GIS .NET will
>   outperform almost all libraries including DotSpatial, SharpMap and
>   even ESRI ArcObjects. If you have any doubts download the largest
>   shapefile you can find and try and open it with Easy GIS .NET.

I've never used Easy GIS .NET, or SharpMap.

Shapefile is considered a slow format to display in questions like [How to improve rendering performance of very large shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37425/how-to-improve-rendering-performance-of-very-large-shapefile)